# Solid state drive on old laptop with Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, ssd, compatibility, pata

I have an old laptop that has a 30 GB HDD (IDE 2.5") and I thought of giving it a little boost by replacing the HDD for a SSD.

Would there be any compatibility problems if do that ?
Does Windows XP support SSDs ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows XP supports SSDs, no problem here.

Although the SSD market for 2.5" drives using the [PATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) interface has been largely ignored, some manufacturers (e.g. [Transcend](http://www.transcendusa.com/Products/ModDetail.asp?ModNo=164&LangNo=0&Func1No=1&Func2No=171), [KingSpec](http://www.kingspec.com/solid-state-disk-products/ssd-25pata-slcj.htm)) do offer those. Also make sure to get an [SLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell#Single-level_cell) type SSD for better performance (as opposed to [MLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell))).

Comment: Yes, SLC drives will conquer performance benchmarks, and should have a greater lifetime. But MLC drives are far cheaper per GB, while still offering excellent performance compared to HDDs. So MLC is the probably the most sensible option for most people.

Comment: Too bad there are no SLC PATA 2.5 SSDs of a decent capacity. The larger one I've found has only 16 GB.

Comment: didn;t you check the link in my post? "Interface: PATA, Flash Type:  SLC, Capacity: 8GB 16GB 32GB 64GB 128GB"

Comment: Yes, but where to buy it?

Comment: however, this rather old laptop of yours may not be worth spending big bucks ona big SSD, so if i were you i'd go for the cheapest model with only 8GB and use USB sticks as storage extension, if necessary. you get decent performance at a price that is reasonable when you consider the age of the laptop. my eee 701 only has a 4 GB SSD which is plenty, i'm using SDHC as extension.

Comment: where to buy? this UK retailer offers some KingSpec PATA SSDs (MLC only): http://www.memoryc.com/search.html?q=kingspec+pata&x=0&y=0

Comment: No problem with MLC, there are plenty of them on eBay. But SLC are rare. A 32GB SLC would be perfect. But I haven't found any.

Comment: TigerDirect? http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/category_slc.asp?CatId=4220

Comment: Neweeg? http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2%2050001364%2040000636%201749646482%201421530855&name=PATA&SpeTabStoreType=1

Comment: or you can order a 32 GB SLC IDE SSD direct from Transcend (for $487, untaxed). as i said, get the 8 Gig model for 90 dollar and expand the storage with USB sticks if you need more. http://ec.transcendusa.com/product/ItemDetail.asp?ItemID=TS32GSSD25-S

Comment: None of them are 32GB SLC. I guess I'll have to pick a MLC from eBay after all.

Comment: didn't you check the LAST link i posted? 32 GB SLC PATA, unfortunately SLC ARE very expensive, but the difference in write speed is like day and night ... now if you think 500 dollar is great investment for that old laptop, fine, but i would NOT settle for MLC, they are painfully slow and not suitable for Windows OS, i told you before, get that 8 GB SLC drive, an economically reasonable choice for 90 dollar, you get top performance, expand storage with USB sticks, 24 GB more storage space but MLC type memory is the worst trade-off.

Answer (score 2):

How old are we talking? I just put an SSD in a Core 2 Duo Lenovo machine that's probably about 5 years old, it was like getting a new computer.

Modern computers seem to be bottle-necked more by HD speed than CPU. If we're talking a Pentium 3 though I'm not sure you'd see an appreciable difference.